# Getting `ValueError` when plotting features with colours on python

Tags: python

I have the following [data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UNwUFWxB5S555qWP5H0S1SKSqRmqTr41?usp=sharing) which needs to be linearly classified using least squares. I wanted to visualise my data and then plot the features with colours but I got the following error when assigning the colour `colour_cond`.

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Note that `data_t` is made of 1s and 0s.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from scipy.io import loadmat

%matplotlib inline

data = glob.glob('Mydata_A.mat')
data_c1 = np.array([loadmat(entry, variable_names= ("X"), squeeze_me=True)["X"][:,0] for entry in data])
data_c2 = np.array([loadmat(entry, variable_names= ("X"), squeeze_me=True)["X"][:,1] for entry in data])
data_t = np.array([loadmat(entry, variable_names= ("T"), squeeze_me=True)["T"][:] for entry in data])

colour_cond=['red' if t==1 else 'blue' for t in data_t]
plt.scatter(data_c1,data_c2,colour=colour_cond)
plt.xlabel('X1')
plt.ylabel('X2')
plt.title('Training Data (X1,X2)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try using `"r"` and `"b"` instead of `"red"` and `"blue"`.

Comment: Did not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the arrays `data_c1`, `data_c2` and `data_t` seem to have more that one dimension. In your following line:

```
colour_cond=['red' if t==1 else 'blue' for t in data_t]
```

the variable `t` is not a scalar but a NumPy array, and `t == 1` is ambiguous for non-scalar NumPy objects. I would suggest you to ravel (i.e. flatten) all your arrays:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import loadmat

%matplotlib inline

data = loadmat('Mydata_A.mat')
data_c1 = np.array([
    loadmat(entry, variable_names=("X"), squeeze_me=True)["X"][:, 0]
    for entry in entries]).ravel()
data_c2 = np.array([
    loadmat(entry, variable_names=("X"), squeeze_me=True)["X"][:, 1]
    for entry in entries]).ravel()
data_t = np.array([
    loadmat(entry, variable_names=("T"), squeeze_me=True)["T"][:]
    for entry in entries]).ravel()

colour_cond = ['red' if t==1 else 'blue' for t in data_t]
plt.scatter(data_c1, data_c2, color=colour_cond)
plt.xlabel('X1')
plt.ylabel('X2')
plt.title('Training Data (X1,X2)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you that worked as expected